# Expression of heat by the Brownian motion

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, brownian-motion, stochastic-processes

folks. I was reading a paper from PRE and I'm not sure what's going on about the following equation. So for the system composed of two heat baths governed by Brownian motion, the entropy change of the Brownian particles are expressed as this (I understood this part)

$$
dS_b = - \frac{dQ_1}{T_1} - \frac{dQ_2}{T_2}
$$
However, the author expressed the $dQ_i$ component by using the Stratonovich notation as 
$$
dQ_i = v_i \circ (-\gamma_i v_i dt + dW_i ).
$$
Here is the quick questions from this equation. (the $dW:=\int_t^{t+dt} dt' \xi_i(t')dt'$) How can I understand this formulation? I don't know what Stratonovich notation means so it bugs me for few days. Is there any reference that I can quickly look over?

Also, the later part the author uses following equation by the Stratonovich product 
$$
v_1 \circ dW_1 :=\frac{1}{2}[v_1 + (v_1 + dv_1)] dW_1 
$$
I also don't get how this definition stands on. Any of your help would be totally appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I don't suppose the first mention of *"Stratonovich notation"* was accompanied by a citation? Alternately the authors of the paper may have provided that citation in an earlier, related paper. I'd would be helpful to have a link or at least the bibliographic data for the paper.

Comment: The authors only cited this textbook without appropriate pages so I'm still confused of it: C. Gardiner, Stochastic Methods, A Handbook for the Natural and Social Sciences (Springer, New York, 2010)

Comment: I'm afraid I'm at a loss. You can either try to get hold of the text in question or make some other kind of literature search for *"Stratonovich notation"*. Or abandon the project if you don't expect the reward to be worth the trouble.

Comment: Stochastic integrals can be defined in a multitude of ways, and each give different results (e.g. Stratonovich has chain rule, whereas with Ito you use Ito's lemma), but they can be relatively easily transformed to one another. Physicists prefer Stratonovich, where the impulse is felt at the middle of a step as this approximates the physical heat bath. Mathematicians prefer Ito integrals and set the impulse at the beginning of each $dt$ so that they can use their machinery (martingales). Google Ito-Stratonovich dilemma (and stochastic differential equations in general) for more.